# Resolve and reject promise from async function within nested function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Given I have the following function:

```
async function foo() {
  document.getElementById('ok').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // How do I resolve from foo here?
  })
  document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // How do I reject from foo here?
  })
}
```

As the comment states, how can I resolve or reject foo's promise within the nested function?

My current solution is:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('ok').addEventListener('click', () => {
      resolve()
    })
    document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
      reject()
    })
  })
}
```

But with this, I have to return the Promise myself rather than using `async`. Is there a better way?

Edit: The example I gave initially was not the best. Updated my question and code.

Comment: As I know any `return` is a `resolve`, `throw` is a `reject`. The function with `async` will automatically *return a `Promise`*

Comment: Without further details, that would be the right way to do it, yes. Async functions aren’t… for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the return value of `bar` from `foo` to resolve the promise, or throw from `bar`, to reject it:

```js
async function foo() {
  const bar = () => {
    return 'Resolved'
    //or `throw 'Rejected'`
  }

  //Where you call `bar`:
  return bar()
}

foo().then(console.log) //Resolved
```

---

**Edit according to the edit made to the question**

You have to promisify all of your asynchronous operations, in order to use them with `async`/`await`.

So, you'll *need* to create a promise like you've done. Then, you can do whatever with that promise.

So, **your approach is completely right** (the only trivial optimization you can do is to avoid creation of additional handler functions):

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('ok').addEventListener('click', resolve)
    document.getElementById('cancel').addEventListener('click', reject)
  })
}
```

Comment: Dang, my example was sh*t as you are right, I could simply return in bar and use that value to return in foo. My problem is that bar is actually a DOM event handler. I'll update my post.